# Não inserir novamente um usuário com login já existente

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, persistência

Estou com um problema em JPA com Java.

Fiz um sistema de login, usando um ID autogerado, mas toda vez que rodo o programa ele cria mais um user no banco de dados, com um id diferente mas mesmas credenciais.

Como faço para que, caso já haja este login de usuário, ele não crie outro igual?

Método que inicia junto com o aplicativo:

```
public void startApp() {

    service = new Service<List<Usuario>>() {
        @Override
        protected Task<List<Usuario>> createTask() {
            return new Task<List<Usuario>>() {
                @Override
                protected List<Usuario> call() throws Exception {

                   Usuario user = new Usuario();
                    user.setNome("Usuario");
                    user.setLogin("user");
                    user.setSenha("123");

                    UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
                    usuarioDAO.inserir(user);
                    return usuarioDAO.obterLista();
                }
            };
        }
    };
```

Método de Inserir do JPA

```
public boolean inserir(Usuario usuario) {
    try {
        entidadeGerenciamento.getTransaction().begin();              
        entidadeGerenciamento.persist(usuario);
        entidadeGerenciamento.getTransaction().commit(); 
        return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia verificar se o usuário, baseando-se pelo login do mesmo, já existe antes de realizar a inserção.

```
public boolean usuarioExistente(Usuario usuario) {
    try {
        Usuario usuario = (Usuario) entidadeGerenciamento.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.login LIKE :login").setParameter("login", "%" + usuario.getLogin() + "%").getSingleResult();
        return true; // Se encontrou registro, então OK!
    } catch (NoResultException ex) {
       return false; // Caso não exista registro
    }
}
```

E seu código para inserir poderia fazer algo:

```
public boolean inserir(Usuario usuario) {
  if (this.usuarioExistente(usuario)) { 
    return false;
  }
  try {
     entidadeGerenciamento.getTransaction().begin();              
     entidadeGerenciamento.persist(usuario);
     entidadeGerenciamento.getTransaction().commit(); 
     return true;
  } // continuação do código
```